# Getting fix data from different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I have this data under my booking.rb model

```
  CATEGORY = [
    'admin',
    'super_admin',
    'normal_customer',
    'member_customer',
  ]
```

Above is fix data, not from any table or database, currently, I wanted to fetch this data under option_select_collection tag from another view booking_groups. Below code are what I have done in my booking_group/index.html

```
<%= select_tag :category, options_from_collection_for_select(Booking.CATEGORY), { prompt: " -- Please select -- ", class: 'form-control' } %>
```

The error appeared an undefined method CATEGORY. Some guideline on what is the function and explanation will help me reading it further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax to call a constant from another namespace is `Booking::CATEGORY`.

Furthermore, when using a simple array instead of a list of complex instance models then you have to use `options_for_select` instead of `options_from_collection_for_select`.

```
<%= select_tag :category, 
               options_for_select(Booking::CATEGORY), 
               prompt: ' -- Please select -- ', class: 'form-control' %>
```

Comment: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 3..4). relation error??

Comment: I updated my answer. There was another issue in your example that I did notice.

Comment: ahh collection and, why I never thought about that. Thanks i learn something here constant data @spickermann